# Extracting value from json from spark table gives SyntaxError error or keyType should be DataType error

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Lets suppose I have such dataframe `org` below:

```text
id |raw
123|{"inn":"123”, "prof": "tkie"}
```

I need to extract from json from column `raw` all `ids` values to new columns, how to do that?

I tried:

```
org.withColumn('inn', from_json($"raw", MapType(StringType, StringType))).withColumn('inn', col('searchcard'.getItem('inn')))
```

got error:

> File "", line 1
> org.withColumn('inn', from_json($"raw", MapType(StringType, StringType))).withColumn('inn', col('searchcard'.getItem('inn')))
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

And:

```
org.withColumn('inn', from_json("raw", MapType(StringType, StringType))).withColumn('inn', col('searchcard'.getItem('inn')))
```

error:

> AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> ----> 1 org.withColumn('inn', from_json("raw", MapType(StringType, StringType))).withColumn('inn', col('searchcard'.getItem('inn')))
> /opt/cloudera/parcels/SPARK2/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in
> **init**(self, keyType, valueType, valueContainsNull)
> 342         False
> 343         """
> --> 344         assert isinstance(keyType, DataType), "keyType should be DataType"
> 345         assert isinstance(valueType, DataType), "valueType should be DataType"
> 346         self.keyType = keyType   AssertionError: keyType should be DataType

Comment: Is this python or scala ? you're mixing the two

Comment: considered python (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method get_json_object did the trick!

```
org.withColumn('inn',get_json_object(org.raw, '$.inn')).show(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You code contains several problems:

- `$"raw"` is used with Scala API, in Pyspark use `col("raw")` or directly as string `"raw"`
- When using `StringType` or any other type, in python you need to add parentheses  `StringType()`
- `getItem` is a Column method but your calling it in string (`'searchcard'.getItem('inn')`)

Here's the same code corrected with complete working example using [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html) function:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, MapType

org = spark.createDataFrame([
    (123, '{"inn":"123", "prof": "tkie"}')
], ["id", "raw"])

org.withColumn(
    'raw',
    F.from_json("raw", MapType(StringType(), StringType()))
).select(
    'id',
    F.col('raw').getItem('inn').alias('inn')
).show()

#+---+---+
#| id|inn|
#+---+---+
#|123|123|
#+---+---+
```